# Forcing .net Login control to make the user logout if a cookie is null

Tags: asp.net, cookies, authentication

I have a code base web application that is connected to 2 databases.  Depending on which login control a user uses to login, a different database is connected to the code.  I am doing all of this by a cookie.  This cookie is in a public class called AuthenticatedUser.  The class looks like this:

```
public class AuthenticatedUser : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public static string ConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            HttpCookie myCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["connectionString"];
            return GetConnectionStringFromName(myCookie);
        }
        set
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["connectionString"] != null)
            {
                ExpireCookies(HttpContext.Current);
            }
            var allCookies = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.AllKeys;
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("connectionString");
            cookie.Value = value;
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(100);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        }
    }

    private static string GetConnectionStringFromName(HttpCookie myCookie)
{
    try
    {
        string connectionStringName = myCookie.Value;
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionStringName].ConnectionString;
    }
    catch
    {
       FormsAuthentication.SignOut();   
    }
     finally
    {
         HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/default.aspx");
    }
    return "";

}        private static void ExpireCookies(HttpContext current)
    {
        var allCookies = current.Request.Cookies.AllKeys;
        foreach (var cook in allCookies.Select(c => current.Response.Cookies[c]).Where(cook => cook != null))
        {
            cook.Value = "";
            cook.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
            current.Request.Cookies.Remove(cook.Name);
            cook.Name = "";
        }
    } 
}
```

This seems to be working on my development machine, but when I tried to deploy it, any user that was using the "remember me" option on the site was getting a null reference error because they did not use the login control to obtain the cookie.

What is the best method to get around this?  I was thinking if a user was logged in but the AuthenticatedUser class could not get a Connectionstring to log out the user to force them to use the login control again.  What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use:

```
try  
{  
      FormsAuthentication.SignOut();  
}  
finally  
{  
      Response.Redirect("~/Home.aspx");  
}
```

This way is preferable, for example if in some time you will decide not- cookie auth, but URL based - the FormsAuthentication will manage it gracefully.

Comment: I have updated the code, is that what you were thinking?  I am trying to test it on my development machine but I am having a hard time replocating the issue.  Is this structured the correct way?

Comment: @EvanGWatkins - actually  FormsAuthentication.SignOut() clears authentication cookies (on condition if you authenticated by ASP.Net standard way, or at least by FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie). So you don't need delete it manually.

Comment: Can you explain a little more?  The membership login is the standard login, so all I need to do is check the cookie (in the try) if it is there great, keep moving, if it is null, logout the user and redirect them to the login.

Comment: @EvanGWatkins - don't re-invent wheel, ASP.Net has reach functionality to support form authentication. You don't need check cookie manually. See class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.aspx .To login use FormsAuthentication.Authenticate or for more advanced usage FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie. To sign-out just call FormsAuthentication.SignOut - which (also) erases the auth cooikies